# react native - redirect screen after register on ajax success

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am trying to redirect to another page after register, I am getting success response in the form of toast but after that navigation not working.
I am getting error 
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigate')**

I tried call navigation using function but no luck.

Register.js

```
handleSubmit(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var data = {
        uname: this.state.uname,
        uemail: this.state.uemail,
        upass: this.state.upass
     }   
     fetch('http://spaceonerents.com/API/api/API/register/submit', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
     }).then(function(response){
         Toast.show('You registered successfully');   
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
     }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
     });
   }
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import ProfileScreen from './Profile';
import LoginScreen from './Login';
import RegisterScreen from './Register';

const AppssNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home : HomeScreen,
    Profile : ProfileScreen,
    Register : RegisterScreen,
    Login : LoginScreen
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
});

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: AppssNavigator,
    Login: AppssNavigator,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './components/AppNavigator';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }  
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: 'handleSubmit' Where does this function run?

Comment: on form submit

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnstyle}
             onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
             <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'blue',}}> Register </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: You first screen is register or drawer??

Comment: does it make any difference ?,
my first screen is home screen then using onclick i go to profile screen , then go to register screen using onclick.
it is testing purpose now, i will change it later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect user to a page after succesful login in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883037/redirect-user-to-a-page-after-succesful-login-in-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in this block of code:

```
 }).then(function(response){
     Toast.show('You registered successfully');   
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
```

Your function is using the `function(){}` syntax, which makes the context of `this` point to within that function, where `this.props` does not exist.

Instead, use arrow notation, which doesn't have it's own context of `this` and lets you reference the higher scope context of `this` where `this.props` does exist:

```
     }).then((response)=>{
     Toast.show('You registered successfully');   
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: Please sir check it out =>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751454/react-native-trying-to-render-single-value-from-json-object-stored-in-localsto

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare a function and pass on the arrows.

```js
.then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
         Toast.show('You registered successfully');   
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . i hope it will works for you.

```
 .then(function (response) {
      Toast.show('You registered successfully');   
      }).then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'))
```

Answer (score 0):

please the code below is from my react native code base, I was a able to fetch the login api from the back end with login success message, but while trying to redirect users to the Dashboard screen with this code
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
params: {
screen: 'Dashboard',
}
});
it wasn't working, users will only receive login success message, but they are not being redirected, anyone who can help?

fetch(InsertAPIURL,
{
method:'POST',
headers: headers,
body: JSON.stringify(Data),
})
.then((response)=>response.json())
.then((response)=>{
if(response == "Login Successful"){

```
                    alert(response[0].Message);
                    
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
                        params: {
                            screen: 'Dashboard',
                          }
                    });
                 }
                 else{
                    alert(response[0].Message);
                }
                })
                .catch((error)=>
                {
                    alert("Error"+error);
                });
```