# react native - trying to render single value from json object stored in localstorage

Tags: json, react-native, local-storage

I created a login component where i stored a json object in asynStorage it is working fine.
Problem is that when i trying to get the value from asynStorage, i am not getting anything on screen.

```
<Text> { this.state.getValue } </Text>
```

This line giving me the whole json like this on screen.

```
[{
  "id":"9",
  "uname":"mine",
  "uemail":"mine@gmail.com",
  "upass":"nomination"
}]
```

I want display the email only so i am writing this line
This line giving me nothing.

```
<Text> { this.state.getValue.uemail } </Text>
```

My component code is like this

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           getValue:''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      let userData = AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(value => {
        this.setState({ getValue : value })
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{marginTop:30, marginLeft:20, marginRight:20, marginBottom:30}}>
            <Text> { this.state.getValue } </Text> 
            <Text> { this.state.getValue.uemail } </Text>          
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

One more thing i need to ask that,
I am using this code in Login component but after pressing logout and removing item from syncStorage it is even going to home screen after that, please tell me why ?.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let userData = AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
  if(userData){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried let userData = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem('user')).then(value => {....
but i am getting json parse error unexpected identifier object

Comment: If you're getting JSON parse error. It means you're trying to parse or stringify an object with invalid syntax.
Make sure to stringify your JSON object before storing, using JSON.stringify(jsonObject)

To convert it back from string to JSON, use JSON.parse(jsonObject)

Answer (score 2):

When working with **AsyncStorage** we must understand that it only keep **strings**. So it only read and write stringified JSON. 
This will work:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getValue: null, //<-- initialize null
    }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(value => {
      this.setState({ getValue: JSON.parse(value) }); //read like a stringified JSON
    });
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Tela2 : {this.state.getValue ? this.state.getValue[0].uemail : ''}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

For write does:

```
  const a = [
    {
      "id": "9",
      "uname": "mine",
      "uemail": "mine@gmail.com",
      "upass": "nomination",
    },
  ];
  AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(a));//<-- stringify your array here
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE: ADD CODE FOR ITERATION IN ARRAY**

Considering the previous code, to render all array elements do it:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getValue: [], //<-- in this case, start as empty array
    }
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <View>
       {this.state.getValue.map(value => {
         return(<Text>{value.uemail}</Text>)
       })}
     </View>
   );
 }
```

Comment: object are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {id,uname,uemail,upass}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use array instead

Comment: Your problem in this question is in AsyncStorage, non in render. And the solution is write and read objects or arrays as strings.

Comment: sir i am trying this code but i am getting empty space at the place of text

Comment: please, put your project in github or other. your problem is in details of implementation.

Comment: I sent an issue for you in github.

Comment: I tried your solution from github but i am getting

object are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {id,uname,uemail,upass}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use array instead

Comment: You are a legend sir, thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
  "id":"9",
  "uname":"mine",
  "uemail":"mine@gmail.com",
  "upass":"nomination"
}]
```

This is an arry so when you are accessing it, access the 0th element of the array and then on that get the uemail property.
 { this.state.getValue[0].uemail }

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.getValue[0].uemail)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value in array so use indices of array to show the value.
You have to use async in componentDidMount because getting data from storage is in async

```
async componentDidMount() {
      let userData =await AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(value => {
        this.setState({ getValue : value })
      });
    }


<Text> { this.state.getValue[0].uemail } </Text>
```

//About this issue.

```
  componentDidMount() {
      let userData = AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      if(userData){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }
    }
```

Again it is the same problem of getting the value from storage works in async. 
Update the code as :

```
async componentDidMount() {
          let userData =await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
          if(userData){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
          }
        }
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.getValue[0].uemail)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code with hooks:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const Home = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(savedData => {
      if (savedData) {
        try {
          const savedUserDetails = JSON.parse(savedData);
          if (savedUserDetails[0]) {
            setUserDetails(savedUserDetails[0]);
          }
        } catch (error) {}
      }
    });
  });

  const {id, uname, uemail, upass} = userDetails;

  return (
    <>
      <Text>{id}</Text>
      <Text>{uname}</Text>
      <Text>{uemail}</Text>
      <Text>{upass}</Text>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: i putted your useEffect function code in componentDidMount but i am getting cant find variable : userDetails

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 3 days and many tries we got the answer 
Thank you @Aristofanio Garcia

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           getValue:[]
        };
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
      let getValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      this.setState({ 
        getValue: JSON.parse(getValue), 
      });        
    }

  render() {

    return (
        <View style={{marginTop:30, marginLeft:20, marginRight:20, marginBottom:30}}>
            <Text style={{color:'black'}}> { this.state.getValue.toString() } </Text> 

            {this.state.getValue.map(member => {
               return(<Text style={{color:'black'}}>{member.uemail}</Text>)
            })}      
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```